# How to link a static library to other static libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

If I have a static library(a.lib) and the others(b.lib, c.lib...) and I want to link b.lib, c.lib... to the a.lib so that I can compile any executable file with a.lib and without b.lib and c.lib, is it possible? If so, how can I do this?

All suggestions are welcome.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` structure

a.lib

```
project(a)
add_library(a a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(a b.lib c.lib)
target_include_directories(a b_headers_dir c_headers_dir)
```

any_executable_file.exe

```
project(any_exec)
add_executable(any_exec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(any_exec a.lib)
target_include_directories(any_exec a_headers_dir b_headers_dir c_headers_dir)
```

Comment: That's not good practice.  Depending on your operating system, you can use the library management tools (like `ar`) to combine all the libraries into one, but if there's an app that also tried to include `b.lib` for their own uses, you'll get conflicts.

Comment: If they're in the same cmake project all you need is `target_link_libraries(any_exec a)` and cmake will do the rest, you don't even need `target_include_directories`

Comment: Static libraries don't link to other libraries.

Comment: `--whole-archive`